# Реализация связи один ко многим в Entity Framework и domain driven design

Tags: c#, entity-framework

У меня есть три сущности: `Region`, `Country`, `City`.
`City` является корневым агрегатом.

Поля `Title` у каждой сущности являются уникальными.

```
public sealed class Country
{
    public Country(Guid id, string title)
    {
        Id = id;
        Title = title;
    }

    public Guid Id { get; private set; }
    public string Title { get; private set; }
}
```

```
public sealed class Region
{
    public Region(Guid id, string title, Country country)
    {
        Id = id;
        Title = title;
        Country = country;
        CountryId = country.Id;
    }

    private Region()
    {
        
    }

    public Guid Id { get; private set; }
    public string Title { get; private set; }
    public Guid CountryId { get; private set; }
    public Country Country { get; private set; }
}
```

```
public sealed class City
{
    public City(Guid id, string title, Region region)
    {
        Id = id;
        Title = title;
        Region = region;
        RegionId = region.Id;
    }

    private City()
    {

    }

    public Guid Id { get; private set; }
    public string Title { get; private set; }
    public Guid RegionId { get; private set; }
    public Region Region { get; private set; }
}
```

Вопрос такой: как правильно сделать метод добавления сущности `City` в базу данных?

Есть репозиторий городов `CityRepository`, там метод `AddAsync`. В нем я ищу в базе регионы и страны в базе и создаю по новой `City`, чтобы была реализована связь один-ко-многим.

```
public async Task AddAsync(City city)
{
    var country = await _context.Countries.FirstOrDefaultAsync(x => x.Title == city.Region.Country.Title);
    if (country is null)
    {
        country = new Country(Guid.NewGuid(), city.Region.Country.Title);
    }

    var region = await _context.Regions.FirstOrDefaultAsync(x => x.Title == city.Region.Title);
    if (region is null)
    {
        region = new Region(Guid.NewGuid(), city.Region.Title, country);
    }

    var existCity = await _context.Cities.FirstOrDefaultAsync(x => x.Title == city.Title);
    if (existCity is null)
    {
        existCity = new City(Guid.NewGuid(), city.Title, region);
    }

    await _context.Cities.AddAsync(existCity);
    await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
}
```

Есть другая реализация этого метода. В другой реализации как параметр метода передаются названия города, региона и страны.

```
public async Task AddAsync(string cityTitle, string regionTitle, string countryTitle)
{
    var country = await _context.Countries.FirstOrDefaultAsync(x => x.Title == countryTitle);
    if (country is null)
    {
        country = new Country(Guid.NewGuid(), countryTitle);
    }

    var region = await _context.Regions.FirstOrDefaultAsync(x => x.Title == regionTitle);
    if (region is null)
    {
        region = new Region(Guid.NewGuid(), regionTitle, country);
    }

    var city = await _context.Cities.FirstOrDefaultAsync(x => x.Title == cityTitle);
    if (city is null)
    {
        city = new City(Guid.NewGuid(), cityTitle, region);
    }

    await _context.Cities.AddAsync(city);
    await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
}
```

Есть какие то другие варианты? Просто такие решения очень громоздкие.
Заранее всем спасибо за помощь.

Comment: Сделайте навигационные свойства-коллекции. В `Country` должна быть `ICollection<Region>`, в `Region` - `ICollection<City>`.

Comment: Спасибо. Попробую